# SvelteKit $navigating store not working on anchor links

Tags: hyperlink, navbar, svelte, sveltekit

I have an app in SvelteKit, and I have a navbar that I want to collapse when the user clicks a link the current code that I have is this:

```
$: if ($navigating) collapseNavbar()
```

This part only executes (collapses the navbar) when the url changes (from `/about` to `/blog`, for example) but not when the anchor changes (ex. from `/about#person1` to `/about#person2`). Is there any way that I can also get it to respond when the anchor link changes?

Answer (score 0):

The window has a [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event) event that you could listen to. Alternatively, maybe you could just collapse on any click outside of the navbar (if that fits the intended logic).